# Why am I getting a value of 0 for my min and max?

Tags: c, max, average, min

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> /* to initialize your random generator */
#define BUFF_SIZE 10
#define FIVE 5
#define TEN 10
#define ZERO 0
#define ONE 1
float min=0;
float max=0;
float average=0;
float input_buffer[BUFF_SIZE+2] = {0};
float output_buffer[FIVE] = {0};
float local_buffer[TEN];
int no_of_data_pts=0;
int function_id=0;

// a function for generating data size, function ID and
// all data, and putting all of it into input_buffer
void generate_data() {
    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    /* Generate a random number: */
    input_buffer[0] = floor(1 + 10*(float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
    input_buffer[1] = floor(1 + 4*(float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < (int)input_buffer[0]; i++ ){
        input_buffer[i+2]=(float)rand()/RAND_MAX;
    }
}

// a function for copying the content of input_buffer into
// local buffer (called here my_buffer)
void reading() {
    no_of_data_pts= (int)input_buffer[0];
    function_id= (int)input_buffer[1];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < no_of_data_pts; i++ ){
        local_buffer[i]=input_buffer[2+i];
    }
}

// a function for processing the content of local buffer;
// it reads function_ID and number of data points from my_buffer
// and saves the results also into my_buffer
void processing() {
    float num=0;
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    float min=0;

    for (i=0; i<no_of_data_pts; i++){
       num = local_buffer[i+1];
       if (num < min) {
           min=num;
       }
    }

    for (i=0;i<no_of_data_pts;i++){
       num = local_buffer[i+1];
       if (num < max) {
           max=num;
       }
    }

    for (i=0;i<no_of_data_pts;i++) {
       sum = sum + local_buffer[i];
    }
    average = sum/no_of_data_pts;
}

// a function for copying the content of my_buffer to the
// output_buffer (according to the patter explained earlier)
void writing() {
    switch (function_id){

        case 1:
            output_buffer[0]= min;
            printf ("Minimum value is: %f ",output_buffer[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            output_buffer[0]= max;
            printf ("Maximum value is: %f ",output_buffer[0]);
            break;
        case 3:
            output_buffer[0]= average;
            printf ("Average value is: %f ",output_buffer[0]);
            break;
        case 4:
            output_buffer[0]= min;
            output_buffer[1]= max;
            output_buffer[2]= average;
            printf ("Minimum, maximum and average value is: %f,%f,%f ",output_buffer[0],output_buffer[1],output_buffer[2]);
            break;
    }


}

int main () {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); 
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0); 
    generate_data();
    reading();
    processing();
    writing();
    return 0;
}
```

So this is for an C assignment.

So when I run this code, it's supposed to generate some random numbers from 0 to 1 and calculate the min, max and average.

The reading of data from the input buffer involves:

- reading a number from the first element of the input buffer, if it is a non-zero number (and it should be), the program performs two following operations, this number represent a number of data points to read (no_of_data_points)
- reading ID of a processing function (function_ID)
- reading all data points
  the ID of data processing function and all points are read into the local buffer

The processing of data involves:

- based on read ID of a processing function specific calculations are performed,
  four different processing can take place:
- if ID is 1: minimum of data points is determined
- if ID is 2: maximum of data points is determined
- if ID is 3: average of data points is determined
- if ID is 4: minimum, maximum and average of data points are determined
  the results should be placed into a local buffer.

The writing of data into the output buffer involves:

- writing a number indicating how many data points are written into the output
  buffer (it includes ID of processing function, and obtained results)
- writing a number, called ID of processing function, indicating what operation was
  performed on data (range from 1 to 4)
- writing the result, and this depends what functions it was:

§ if ID is 1: value of minimum is written

§ if ID is 2: value of maximum is written

§ if ID is 3: value of average is written

§ if ID is 4: values of minimum, maximum and average are written

I then print the results at the very end of the program.

The code runs fine. There are no errors BUT for some reason, I CANNOT figure out why the values of min and max are always 0! My value for average is fine but my max and min values are always 0 for some reason and that's not right.

Comment: 1 ) Can you please post the code here? 2) `Title` is for ___Title___. Not meant to write the __body__.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  We can't help you if you don't provide your code, specifically the part that is not working for you.

Comment: I can't format it properly. I attached a link.

Comment: "*I can't format it properly.*" What?

Comment: Alright. I fixed everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, this

```
   if (num < max) {
       max = num;
   }
```

shall be

```
   if (num > max) {
       max = num;
   }
```

at least.

---

Also using the above approach with initialising `min` and `max` to `0` might not work for any kind of input.

To be sure to detect all possiblities of input initialise

```
min = FLT_MAX;
```

and

```
max = -FLT_MAX;
```

---

If the smallest/largest possible values are unknown for any reason, change the way how `min` and `max` are being detected:

```
void processing() {
  float num=0;
  int i;
  float sum = 0;

  min = local_buffer[1];
  for (i = 1; i < no_of_data_pts; i++){
    num = local_buffer[i + 1];
    if (num < min) {
       min = num;
    }
  }

  max = local_buffer[1];
  for (i = 1; i < no_of_data_pts; i++){
    num = local_buffer[i + 1];
    if (num > max) {
       max = num;
    }
  }

  ...
```

---

Also^2 the code defines `min` twice:

1. globally
2. local to `processing()`, shadowing 1.

Remove the 2<sup>nd</sup> definition.

---

The code misses to protoype `floor()`. That's why the compiler assume it to return an `int`. This might invoke undefined behaviour.

To fix this add

```
#include <math.h>
```

---

Also^3 when reading out `local_buffer` in `processing()` the code use the wrong indexing. The index starts at `0` not at `1`. So it is always reading out a last value which had not been set by the generator. That's finally were the `0` for `min` comes from.

Correcting this would make the above snippet from `processing()` look like:

```
void processing() {
  float num=0;
  int i;
  float sum = 0;

  min = local_buffer[0];
  for (i = 1; i < no_of_data_pts; i++){
    num = local_buffer[i];
    if (num < min) {
       min = num;
    }
  }

  max = local_buffer[0];
  for (i = 1; i < no_of_data_pts; i++){
    num = local_buffer[i];
    if (num > max) {
       max = num;
    }
  }

  ...
```

---

Final notes:

1. Listen to your compiler, take its warnings serious.
2. You might like to take into to consideration learning how to use a debugger, to be able to figure such issues on your own the next time.

Comment: That takes care of max. What about min?

Comment: Apparantly FLT_MAX or FLT_MIN isn't recognized.

Comment: Replace them with the smallest/largest possible values for `float`s on your system. @SubhashisChakraborty

Comment: Okay I did all of that. Minimum is still shown as 0. I tried to debug this printing the value at min. The error is definitely at min = num. Output is still 0.

Comment: The logical conculsion from this is that your generator does not generate negative numbers. So you might like to try debugging the generator. @SubhashisChakraborty Reading this might help: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html

Comment: That's fine. But should it also not display the smallest value for min? It doesn't necessarily have to be negative to be the smallest.

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty: You did remove the definition of `min` local to `processing()`?

Comment: Yep. I debugged it similarly. I printed the results at each output to check where the problem is and it is indeed at the min part.

Yes I removed the 2nd definition. It's still 0 somehow.

Comment: This shouldn't be `FLT_MIN` but `-FLT_MAX`, I think.

Comment: If I debug this, the for loop for min, never stores the value of num as min for some reason.

Comment: See my updated and final answer. @SubhashisChakraborty

Comment: @alk: Nope. The output is still 0. If I go through the debugger, the value is never stored in num ever since it shows num is ALWAYS < min for some reason.

Comment: Ahh!!! This is still giving me 0 I "cleaned it" and did a rebuild of the project. The output for min is STILL 0!!!

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty: debug your code carefully. Check each value, condition etc.